# Electron WebView CSS Border Radius

Tags: html, css, webview, electron

Does [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/)'s [<webview>](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag) tag support having a border radius? If not, is there a reference to which styles are supported?

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <aside>

    </aside>
    <main>
        <webview id="view" src="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb"></webview>
    </main>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}

aside {
    min-width: 88px;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px 9px 9px 0px;
}

#view {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**Result**
[image: Electron WebView Border Radius]

As can be seen from the result, the border radius is *technically* applied, since the red border falls behind the webview. In contrast, the blue outline falls in front of the webview, however the border radius seems to be ignored by the webview itself, leaving the context hanging outside the bounds of the radius.

Comment: I don't think this is in any way specific to electron / using a webview - with any run-of-the-mill iframe, you would have the exact same issue. Simply add `overflow: hidden` to `#view` ...?

Comment: @CBroe I would never have guessed that `overflow` would have solved it, but it did! Many thanks!

Comment: @CBroe ps, if you make this an answer, I'll upvote and accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to electron / using a webview - with any run-of-the-mill iframe, you would have the same issue. These are effectively "window" instances, and those do not adhere to a border-radius on the parent container by default, but "break out" of that.

Adding `overflow: hidden` to `#view` should solve it.